# ASP.net inline on a page

Tags: asp.net, repeater

Hoping an ASP.net expert can help me out here, this is very simple but I've been fooling around with syntax long enough to know that I don't know.

I simply want to inline an if block on a page.  If the listing is sponsored, I want to display their website address.  What does the syntax look like for this?

```
//This is what I've been getting at:

    <% if(Eval("Sponsored_Listing")=="Yes") {
         //Then I want to simply write the URL on the page.
         <a href="http://<#% Eval("Website") %>"><%# Eval("Website") %></a>
    else { 
         //Do nothing -- nothing is written to screen.
    }    
%>
```

I have a feeling this is an issue with preprocessor directives.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this inside a Repeater, DataGrid or similar?

Comment: Yes it is in a repeater.

Comment: `Eval` should only be used inside of Databind blocks, not codeblocks.

Comment: Mind explaining further?  Not sure what that terminology really means (I'll attempt a Google), but are you talking about my first Eval I use?

Comment: You're going in the wrong way. While it might work, it's bad practice. Good practice is overriding [ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx) event and have the logic there, not in the markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Eval` returns object, so you need to cast to string.

```
<%# Eval("Sponsored_Listing").ToString() =="Yes" ? 
    string.Format("<a href=\"http://{0}\">{0}</a>", Eval("Website")) : "" %>
```

**Another thought** - if you want to perform a logic, you would like to suggest to use [ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx) method. It is much more clearer and supports strong type.

Comment: Cool, this looks very helpful indeed.  What are the {0} for?  Does that just refer to the above object?

Comment: Yes, string.format makes the code a bit cleaner and easy to read.

Comment: Since you are new to `StackOverFlow`, if this answers your question, please check it as `Answer` so that it'll help others who look for the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Correct way to do it:

```
 <%if (Eval("Sponsered_Listing") == "Yes")

      { 
      //write the Url

          Response.Write("<a href='Http://" + Eval("WebSite")  + "'>" + Eval("WebSite") + "</a>");

      }
```

regards